Prevent toggleBtn and menu from toggling on list item click in JavaScript
on Clicking the list items when the toggleBtn is active, then active class is removed from toggleBtn and menu class, I am not able to understand the reason for this behaviour, I have tried stopPropogation in js file, but its not working, I have also tried pointer-events in css file, but its of no use


let menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggleBtn');
let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
let list = document.querySelectorAll('li');

menuToggle.onclick = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle('active');
    menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
}


list.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click',
    function () {
        list.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active'));
        this.classList.add('active');
}))
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: #222327;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.menu{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu .toggleBtn{
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    color: #0f0;
    border: 2px solid #0f0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 3em;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu .toggleBtn.active{
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    background: #0f0;
    color: #222327;
}

.menu li{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    transform-origin: 140px;
    border: 2px solid #0f0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg / 8 * var(--x))) translateX(40px);
    z-index: 10;
    pointer-events: none;
    scale: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--x))
}

.menu.active li{
    scale: 1;
    pointer-events: initials;
}

.menu li a{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    color: #0f0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg / -8 * var(--x)));
}

.menu li.active a{
    background: #0f0;
    color: #222327;
}
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <div class="toggleBtn">
            <ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <li style="--x:0">
            <a href=""> <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>
        <li style="--x:1">
            <a href=""> <ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>

        <li style="--x:2">
            <a href=""><ion-icon name="videocam-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>

        <li style="--x:3">
            <a href=""><ion-icon name="build-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>
        <li style="--x:4">
            <a href="">
                <ion-icon name="game-controller-outline"></ion-icon>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li style="--x:5"><a href="">
                <ion-icon name="camera-outline"></ion-icon>
            </a></li>
        <li style="--x:6">
            <a href=""><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>
        <li style="--x:7">
            <a href=""><ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



I want that on clicking the list items, it should not toggle the toggleBtn and menu

Your issue is unclear and hard to understand, revise your question.

Remove the pointer-events: none; from the css on the li. that does so you cant click it

Your code works fine for me. The only thing is that I had to remove the pointer-events: none from the list items.

Please remove pointer-events:none from .menu li in CSS and add that to .menu li a if you want to add active class without redirect page


let menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggleBtn');
let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
let list = document.querySelectorAll('li');

menuToggle.onclick = () => {

    menu.classList.toggle('active');
    menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
}

list.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click',
    function () {
        list.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active'));
        this.classList.add('active');
}))
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: #222327;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.menu{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu .toggleBtn{
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    color: #0f0;
    border: 2px solid #0f0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 3em;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu .toggleBtn.active{
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    background: #0f0;
    color: #222327;
}

.menu li{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    transform-origin: 140px;
    border: 2px solid #0f0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg / 8 * var(--x))) translateX(40px);
    z-index: 10;
    scale: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--x))
}

.menu.active li{
    scale: 1;
}

.menu li a{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    color: #0f0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg / -8 * var(--x)));
    pointer-events: none;
}

.menu li.active a{
    background: #0f0;
    color: #222327;
    border-radius:50%;
    
}
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <div class="toggleBtn">
            <ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <li style="--x:0">
            <a href=""> <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>
        <li style="--x:1">
            <a href=""> <ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>

        <li style="--x:2">
            <a href=""><ion-icon name="videocam-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>

        <li style="--x:3">
            <a href=""><ion-icon name="build-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>
        <li style="--x:4">
            <a href="">
                <ion-icon name="game-controller-outline"></ion-icon>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li style="--x:5"><a href="">
                <ion-icon name="camera-outline"></ion-icon>
            </a></li>
        <li style="--x:6">
            <a href=""><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>
        <li style="--x:7">
            <a href=""><ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



